# run tornado with aiomysql in multi-process mode

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, python-asyncio

I have been trying to run tornado with aiomysql in multi-process mode with the following code

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def get_mysql_connection(loop):
    return (yield from aiomysql.create_pool(host=host,port=3306,user=user, password=pass, db=db, loop=loop))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
    ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    mysql = ioloop.run_until_complete(get_mysql_connection(ioloop))
    options.parse_config_file("app.conf")
    app = make_app(mysql)
    print('listening on %s:%s...' %(options.host, options.port))
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    server.listen(options.port)
    server.start(0) #this is my problem
    ioloop.run_forever()
```

But I keep getting the below error

```
RuntimeError: Cannot run in multiple processes: IOLoop instance has already been initialized. You cannot call IOLoop.instance() before calling start_processes()
```

Everything is working fine except for the `ioloop.start(0)` line, is it possible to make the two libraries `aiomysql` and `tornado` work nicely in multi-process mode? If no what are my other options

**Tornado version 4.4.2**

**python version 3.6.0**

**aiomysql version 0.0.9**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the message says, you can only fork worker processes if you do it *before* the IOLoop is initialized. This gets a little delicate with AsyncIOMainLoop since you want to install that as early as possible. The solution is to start your program with this sequence:

```
tornado.options.parse_config_file(...)
socks = tornado.netutil.bind_sockets(options.port, options.host)
tornado.process.fork_processes(0)
tornado.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
# Initialize the rest of your app, create the HTTPServer, 
# and instead of listen() or start(), do
server.add_sockets(socks)
```

> what are my other options

In my opinion it's better to use an external process manager like `supervisord` instead of forking multiple processes within your app. That avoids most of these initialization-order traps.

Comment: Your code works fine but the server exited immediately so I had to run `asyncio` event loop with `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever().start()`

Comment: Yeah, you still need to start the event loop like usual. The comment about "instead of start()" was referring to `HTTPServer.start()`, not `IOLoop.start()` (or `get_event_loop().run_forever()`)